# Spring MongoTemplate executeCommand Result more than first batch

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring-data-mongodb 3.3.1 to run an native MongoDB query as followings:

```
String jsonCommand = "{ aggregate: 'CollectionName', pipeline: [ { $match: ...... ] , cursor: { } };
Document commandResult = mongoTemplate.executeCommand(jsonCommand);
List<Document> documents = (List<Document>) ((Document) commandResult.get("cursor")).get("firstBatch");
```

The query returns 101 documents which is the default batchSize. My question is, the query result does not contain all the matched documents and I want to repeat this query until I get all the matched documents. My question is:

How can I check if there are more documents beyond the "firstBatch", and, if yes, repeat the same query until I get all the results?

I know I can hardcode a bigger batchSize as follows:

```
cursor: { batchSize: 10000 }
```

But this is not what I want. I want to know the way to retrieve the documents in multiple batches.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The result document `commandResult` has info about the returned cursor. One of the fields is the cursor identifier `id` (it is a `long` number, e.g.,  `Long("2853629826122579707")`). Further, you use this `id`. Use the [getMore](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/getMore/) command to find and return the remaining documents after the first batch.